# Table View, View Controller, Table Cell nil error

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've created a ViewController with my Storyboard linked to it. I've done this before and it has worked fine. This time tho, when I use almost the exact same code for the table view and the table view cell, it returns a nil error when running. I am not sure what the reason exactly is.

```
//
//  IngView1.swift
//  Fake
//
//  Created by Ian Dong on 11/16/20.
//

import UIKit

class IngView1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        display.dataSource = self
    }
    
    var data = ["Oil     5","Beef     3","Chicken     5","Potato     4","Cheese     3","Fish     3","Cabage     4"]
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IngReUse")! // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        let text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use this version instead?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell

Comment: what do you mean? should I look into this ?

Comment: There is an important yellow warning there. You should register your cell with an identifier to dequeue it.

Comment: @IanDONG  How about reading the reference and then decide?

Comment: I've given my cell a Restoration ID

Comment: @PhillipMills I've read it, I'm just a little confused on do I add this after the ".' notation in "tableView....." or it whole function, and what should I input as the index path?

Comment: You have to set the *Identifier* of the cell in IB properly, it's **not** the Restoration ID.

Comment: omg youre a legend thank you guys soo much

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you properly set prototype cell's identifier? You can do this in the storyboard.

Or if you're not using prototype cell, you can register it in code

```
display.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IngReUse")
```

Comment: If you use ***prototype cell*** you must not register the cell.

Comment: You are right, @vadian. Thanks, I edited my answer.